# Asserting I have received 10 messages

Tags: java

I'm trying to assert the fact I have received 10 messages from pubnub. I do infact receive them to the console. However what would be the right way to assert that I have. I'm not entirely sure on what syntax I should use.

```
@Test
public void testPublisher() throws PubnubException {



     // Send 10 messages
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        service.publish("my_channel", "Message: " + i);
    }

    // Wait until we have recieved the 10 messages
    do{}while(service.count() <= 10);

    // For each message print out the details
    service.getMessages().forEach(System.out::println);

    assertArrayEquals(service.count());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use
`assertTrue(service.count() == 10);`

Comment: This works but it fails for another reason. Thank you.

Comment: `assertEquals(service.count(), 10);` is pregnant a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: If you're being idiomatic it should be `assertEquals(10, service.count())`

Comment: This answer is not very good. If the test fails it simply gives you "Expected true but got false" without any further clue on what was actually tested. Asserting on the expected number is much better but you should probably add a message to the assertion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `do...while` loop is known as a "busy spin" which is considered an anti-pattern in most cases and should be avoided. Busy spinning thrashes the CPU whilst it waits and your implelemtation could also run eternally if something goes wrong and 10 messages aren't received.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

You should consider a blocking mechanism... possibly with a timeout such as
[BlockingQueue.take()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) or [BlockingQueue.poll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) or [CountdownLatch.await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)